# Count specific characters within a class (and apply text truncate logics to each instance of that class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML like

```
<a href="/blabla" class="matchupLink">
    <span class="teams"> USA</span>
    <strong> -0 </strong>
    <span class="teams">Netherlands</span>
    <span class="pull-right dateOrScore"><strong>15 Jul</strong> : 3:00pm CST</span>
</a>

<a href="/blabla2" class="matchupLink">
    <span class="teams"> USA</span>
    <strong> -0 </strong>
    <span class="teams">Netherlands</span>
    <span class="pull-right dateOrScore"><strong>15 Jul</strong> : 3:00pm CST</span>
</a>

<a href="/blabla3" class="matchupLink">
    <span class="teams"> USA</span>
    <strong> -0 </strong>
    <span class="teams">Netherlands</span>
    <span class="pull-right dateOrScore"><strong>15 Jul</strong> : 3:00pm CST</span>
</a>
```

I want to count the number of characters that's inside each "matchupLink" class, but without counting the characters inside the "dateOrScore" class.

My goal is to then cut the text and put ellipses after char 20 if char count is over 20 characters, while keeping the date (dateOrScore) element there.

I tried something like

```
$('.matchupLink .teams').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).html())
});
```

But that returns every `teams` element individually, can't really use the ellipses logics that way.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Ps: I also tried taking all text, and excluding 'dateOrScore' (using not()) but that also failed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
var ellipses = 20;

$('.matchupLink').children().not('.dateOrScore').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(text.length > ellipses)
        $(this).text(text.substr(0, ellipses) + '...');
});
```